# NoneType object Not callable

Tags: python-3.x

## Nonetype object is not callable

could anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
def edit(function):
    def after():
        print('''**************************''')
        function()
        print('''**************************''')
    return after()


@edit
def func1():
    print("Saurav!")

func1()
```

Answer (score 0):

decorator need return a function. your code return a Nonetype. try this

```py
def edit(function):
    def after():
        print('''**************************''')
        function()
        print('''**************************''')
    return after
```

the code

```
@edit
def func1()
```

is equals `edit(func1)()`